# The right way to return an object inside of a list

Tags: c#, list, object, methods, return

When I try to return the kart list, where I populate my object, I get "systems.collections.generic.list" How do I return kart the right way?

Method

```
    public class AddToKart
    {
        public static List<KartItem> PutItemInKart(string input, int inputNumber, double inputPrice)
        {
            List<KartItem> kart = new List<KartItem>();
            kart.Add(new KartItem() {
                Item = input,
                Pound = inputNumber,
                Cost = inputPrice
            });;
            return kart;
        }
    }
```

Object retrieving data

```
 public class KartItem
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public int Pound { get; set; }
        public double Cost { get; set; }

        public KartItem(string item, int pound, double cost)
        {
            Item = item;
            Pound = pound;
            Cost = cost;
        }
        public KartItem()
        {
        }
    }
```

test for method PutItemInKart testing item pounds and cost 
from object.

```
  [Fact]
        public void AddToKartMethodItem()
        {
            //Arrange
            string expected = "fdfdfsds";

            //Act
            List<KartItem> items = AddToKart.PutItemInKart(expected, 3, 4.5);
            string actual = items[0].Item;

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void AddKartMethodPound()
        {
            int expected = 3;
            List<KartItem> numbers = AddToKart.PutItemInKart("mingt", expected, 4.45);
            int actual = numbers[0].Pound;
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void AddToKartMethodCost()
        {
            double expected = 34.56;
            List<KartItem> cost = AddToKart.PutItemInKart("fdsf", 5, expected);
            double actual = cost[0].Cost;
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
```

Comment: You are returning it the right way. The problem is what you are doing with the result returned by `PutItemInKart()`. Please show us that code, and we can help you fix it. Are you passing the result directly to `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: When you look at an object in the debugger, the debugger will call `ToString` on the object in order to display a string that describes the object.  If a class has not overridden the `ToString` method, then the base class version is used.  The base class of all classes is `System.Object` and `System.Object.ToString` simply returns what it knows about the object - the name of it's class.

Comment: This method always returns a new Kart with only 1 item. Your cart can only have 1 item? Maybe the Logic is flawed? Can you show us all the code?

Comment: Where are you seeing "systems.collections.generic.list"?

Comment: @Train I have included the KartItem. I hope this helps more.

Comment: Your constructor is wrong, you have `item = Item` you need `Item = item`... for all of those variables. Also show us the code where it's being used not just the class.

Comment: I am running the method through testing and am getting my error from that. I have included my test class for the method. I am sorry, I am trying to learn c# and am not effectively able to express my problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am seeing it from my test result posted

Answer (score 3):

That's depending on the scenario you are using.
From your code I can figure out that you must have a class KartContainer which must includes all operations related karts.

```
    public class KartContainer
    {
        private List<KartItem> Items = new List<KartItem>();

        public void AddItem(KartItem item)
        {
            Items.Add(KartItem);
        }

        public List<KartItem> GetItems()
        {
            return Items;
        }
    }
```

> And you can use it as the following:

```
        KartContainer kart = new KartContainer();

        KartItem item = new KartItem()
        {
            Item = "",
            Pound = 1,
            Cost = 1
        }

        kart.AddItem(item);
        List<KartItem> Items = kart.GetItems();
```

> UPDATE: After your post update I would like to draw your attention about constructor definition, you must assign constructor parameters to local variables not the opposite.

```
    public KartItem(string item, int pound, double cost)
    {
        Item = item;
        Pound= pound;
        Cost = cost;
    }
```

Comment: -__- thank you!   My brain slows down after looking at code for so long lol